# How to search for another file if one doesn't exist and use it?

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script that can locate a file, and if it's not there (or if the spelling is wrong) use another file.

From what I have seen - there seems to be only answers to write the host, which I don't want it to do. After doing some research, it seems like an `if` statement is the way forward, but I am having issues with it. Have gotten (but could be wildly wrong):

```
$test = if (Test-Path 'C:\test1') else (Test-Path 'C:\test2')
```

Comment: `$test = & { (Test-Path 'C:\test1') -or (Test-Path 'C:\test2') }` (variable `$test` will be `$true` if either path exists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? [You should really use Google for getting to grips with basic syntax](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_if_statement.htm)

```
$filePath1 = 'C:\test1'
$filePath1 = 'C:\test2'

if (Test-Path $filePath1){
    $test = $filePath1
}Elseif(Test-Path $filePath2){
    $test = $filePath2
}Else{
    Write-Host "Neither file exits."
}
```